# Visual C# - How can I layer the status strip to be behind my list view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, statusstrip

When I resize my window, the StatusStrip I have located at the bottom of the form sits on top of the ListView.
How I can set the StatusStrip to be behind the list view?

Comment: Thanks, guys! I figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! You just have to right click on the StatusStrip and click "Send To Back"

Answer (score 0):

Set `Anchor` property of `StatusStrip` to `Bottom`, or you can add the code on maximize -  `statusStrip.SendToBack()`